# What does Bell's Theorem really violate?

Tags: bells-inequality

Well this is a fairly straightforward question. I know it states that either hidden variables is wrong or Quantum Mechanics. But indirectly hidden variables is a part of QM due to uncertainty. So what exactly does it violate. I am just a bit confused.

Comment: "But indirectly hidden variables is a part of QM due to uncertainty" 

What do you mean? You should realize that Bell's theorem tells us **there are no local hidden variables**, there is nothing to know than what QM can give us.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What combinations of realism, non-locality, and contextuality are ruled out in quantum theory?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7276/)

Comment: The common sense of young self-respecting humans is what it violates.

Comment: @Danu Well, it is Bell's theorem plus certain experimental results that tell us that. The theorem just says that a theory with local hidden variables in distinguishable from one without them. And it doesn't violate anything, except the expectations that BMS refers to.